# Track specific IP over BitTorrent trackers

Tags: privacy, bittorrent

I am wondering whether is possible to track specific IPs over some torrent trackers without collecting information about the whole tracker.

For example: http://iknowwhatyoudownload.com/en/peer/

They are parsing torrent sites to get torrent hashes, but it is possible to force tracker to send you torrent metadata the specific IP is seeding.

Comment: What will you do with the IP? As long as you don't want to send or receive data right now this information is pretty much worthless. IP adresses are dynamically allocated and cannot be used to identify and/or track individuals

Comment: If we send mail to target@company.com contains image that is hosted on our server we can obtain targets´s IP, so we can connect IP and mail (leave out option that target checked mail on smartphone, in cafe..). 
If it will be possible to extract information about seeding in some reasonable time we could find what torrents have the target downloaded, so the attacker can specify phishing mail, blackmail etc.

Comment: leaving out the possebility that the user might be using Outlook or Thunderbird. Both block remote content by default. If it really is a company-address then all employees of the building share the same internet connection and thus the same IP.

Comment: I´ve totally forgotten about Thunderbird. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. You can only do the same thing as the site you linked and request peers for as much torrent hashes as you can and filter the results you get.

If you try to query trackers this way beware that some of them [add random IPs](https://torrentfreak.com/the-pirate-bay-tricks-anti-pirates-with-fake-peers-081020/?doing_wp_cron=1492114113.6378850936889648437500) into the peer list to prevent these kind of things. A tracker just returning an IP is no proof for that IP actually seeding / leeching that torrent.

Also a little side note about the link you posted: they do not only query torrent trackers or indexers but also the [DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT), a distributed alternative to trackers.